# where do i set the licence_proxy_url in nginx for passegner enterprise?

Tags: passenger

Im running passenger inside of a docker container, in a highly controlled host environment. It requires all outbound traffic be sent through a proxy. Ive configured docker and such to use this proxy. Im trying to configure the license and security checks to use the same proxy.

Installed using system ruby gems.

base docker image is redhat/ubi-8
passenger-enterprise 6.0.20
nginx bundled with 6.0.20
ruby 3.0.5

When i try to launch, the license check fails as a proxy is required.
The error that comes up says passsenger_ctl should be set. However it doesnt says where, i can find no other documentation on this directive and find release notes stating that that key is incorrect and should be licensw_proxy_url

where is this directive valid? or is this some command trigger to passenger-config